# Comparing column counts between 2 tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables with the same columns.  One table has been updated and the other one is a back up.  I need to compare the counts on a particular column that is present in the 2 tables and need to see what column counts are not the same.

**I have this query thus far:**

```
select a.id, count(a.last_name), b.id, count(b.last_name)
from updatedTable a
join backupTable b on a.id = b.id
group by a.contact_id, b.contact_id
```

The above query ran, but I want to know this:
**where count(a.last_name) <> count(b.last_name)**

Comment: have you tried that?  (place after your group by - where count(a.last_name) != count(b.last_name)

Comment: I did, but got an error message.  I ran the query in the 'Answer' below and it worked.  I was able to run my own query by adding 'having count(a.matchkey_id) <> count(b.matchkey_id)' after 'group by'

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you really want

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.id, count(a.last_name) num_last_names
          FROM tableA a
         GROUP BY a.id) a
       INNER JOIN
       (SELECT b.id, count(b.last_name) num_last_names
          FROM tableB b
         GROUP BY b.id) b
       ON( a.id = b.id )
 WHERE a.num_last_names != b.num_last_names
```

This groups each table separately, then does the join and compares the data from the aggregated columns.

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I was looking for!